# Unable to run Spring REST application using Tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, tomcat

I have spent the weekend trying to run some simple Spring REST applications. Lots of examples on the net. However, whenever I got to running these, my application would always give me a 404 - Resource not found exception. To ensure I was doing everything right, I even restarted the applications from scratch a few times.

If I go to the project folder and run mvn tomcat7:run the project works as expected. However, when adding the project to my Tomcat7 server inside Eclipse and running it there, I always get a 404 error.

Any ideas on what is going wrong would be greatly appreciated.

[image: project layout 1]

[image: project layout 2]

Comment: Are you using Maven?

Comment: Yes. This is basically what I followed: http://websystique.com/springmvc/spring-4-mvc-rest-service-example-using-restcontroller/  The one difference though is that it did not add the src/main/java folder. I had to manually create that.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is `src/main/java` `folder` , you said you manually create it. so you did not add it to **Source** after create it?

**Update**
i just import the code to eclipse,and i modify the **`Web Module`** **`Path`**,and it worked. here is the snap:
[image]

and the test url
[image]

hope this is useful.

Comment: Yes, I did add it to the Source file after creating it.

Comment: can u post your project structure snap. or after maven build, in the war package, is there class folder or your java class file.

Comment: hello @DavidR did u find any solution? i followed the site you post,and it  worked. i will edit the answer later.