# Spring Framework Project not loading?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, tomcat

I have been working with the Spring framework for a few days trying to set up a project, based off of something like [this tutorial](http://websystique.com/springmvc/spring-4-mvc-and-hibernate4-integration-example-using-annotations/).

Unfortunately, when i deploy the project using Tomcat, I get a screen that looks something like this:

[image: Tomcat 404 error]

I'm not really sure to go from here. I've checked the web.xml and any other relevant .xml files that would maybe affect the error, but I can't see an error. Below I will post my `web.xml` and `spring-config.xml` files.

**web.xml**

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   
       http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"  
 version="2.5">  

 <display-name>Campaign Spring V2</display-name>  

 <servlet>  
  <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>  
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>  
  <init-param>  
   <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>  
   <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-config.xml</param-value>  
  </init-param>  
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>  
 </servlet>  

    <servlet-mapping>  
      <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>  
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>  
     </servlet-mapping>  

    </web-app>
```

**spring_config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd  
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd  
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd  
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.bridge.campaignspring.controller" />

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties" />

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${database.user}" />
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.bridge.campaignspring.Campaign</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="CampaignDao" class="com.bridge.campaignspring.dao.CampaignDAOImpl" />
    <bean id="CampaignService" class="com.bridge.campaignspring.service.CampaignServiceImpl" />

</beans>
```

If need be, I can post the project to GitHub to see if there is an even larger flaw that could be found in the code. Also, if any other parts of the project need to be posted I will update the OP to display anything. Thanks!

**EDIT:** http://localhost/ does not load either, I was incorrect with my previous statement.

**EDIT2:** Here is a link to the project on [GitHub](https://github.com/daperez/CampaignSpringV2).

**EDIT3:** After going through the Spring tutorial again this was resolved!

Comment: Look if you get errors on deployment

Comment: @Jens this is the entire stack trace from when I run the project on the server: http://pastebin.com/hwM3MW0v

Comment: here is your problem: `Ambiguous mapping found. Cannot map 'dataController' bean method`

Comment: How would I resolve that?

Comment: The code is not working because it doesn't have a controller.

Comment: @RomanC how can I resolve the controller issue?

Comment: @xtheking it's explained in the p. 6 of the tutorial.

Comment: @RomanC I'm updating the OP to have a link to the project; I do in fact have AppController.java in my files.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't follow the tutorial well. The controller mapping starts with

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public class AppController {
```

The first annotation `@RequestMapping("/")` is important for spring to calculate the path used by the request.

And this code is missing

```
@Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.bridge.compaignspring.model" });
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactory;
     }
```

Without it Spring cannot autowire properties that depend on `sessionFactory`.

Comment: Why you are using xml configuration, in the tutorial it's annotation based?

Comment: I'm fairly new to the Spring framework; I saw the XML on a previous tutorial and tried to adapt it. Evidently, it has just muddled up the code. Should I remove the XML files?

Comment: yes, you can because It's just misleading to the wrong source, spring 4 in the link and last update on git is using annotation based config. Are you sure the service is wired and working?

Comment: I;ve removed the .xml files; Git should reflect the changes. What you do you mean by "wired and working"?

Comment: Where should I paste the code that you just edited into your post? The @Bean section

Comment: In `HibernateConfiguration.java`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88492/discussion-between-xtheking-and-roman-c).

Comment: You already made additional changes to connect to the database. But if database doesn't exist you should create it manually via `create database` and add property `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update` to populate schema  on the first start.

Answer (score 0):

Just done a quick check through the github project, you have more problems that I thought.

You are using XML config to create the DispatchServer with the config at Spring-config.xml, while **also** having a `AppInitializer` on the class path.

The AppInitializer uses AppConfig which creates a Datasource bean, your XML also creates a Datasource bean and also a SessionFactory.

Tomcat will find the AppInitializer and is running through that first.
This means it tries to autowire the SessionFactory before the one in the XML have been created.
To move your code off this problem do the following things.

move spring_config.xml from /webapp/WEB-INF to /resources

add the following @import line to AppConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ImportResource("classpath:spring-config.xml")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.bridge.campaignspring")
public class AppConfig {
```

Now you need to remove 1 of the 2 DataSource beans you are creating. I would suggest removing the one in the XML as that is using invalid property values. i.e. `${database.driver}` does not exist.

After you have made those changes, you will still have other problems, but you are further along than you were.

Comment: I just removed the XML due to confusion, so now it should be purely annotation based. Any ideas from there?

Comment: I assumed XML was some critical requirement, hence why you deviated from the tutorial. But if you really don't need it, then download the sourcecode from the original tutorial and start again. There is too much broken here.

Answer (score 0):

did u set `Web Module Path` in `tomcat settings` ?

refer these question [Unable to run Spring REST application using Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32302412/unable-to-run-spring-rest-application-using-tomcat/32302774#32302774)